# splitview with multiple detail views and navcontroller only works once

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I used the Apple splitview with multiple detail views example.
I have several different detail views, some of them have navigationcontrollers, so I can do a pushViewController to push a "settings page" for example.
In the xib file I have to specify a specific detailview as the "Class" which happens to be the first detailView.
When I run the program I am able to push a new view from the first detail view, but when I navigate away from the view by clicking on another detaiview then go back to the first detailView, the pushsubview doesn't work.

Note:If I do this with just 1 detailviewcontroller this works fine.  Something seems to get disconnected when I change to multiple detailviewcontrollers

Comment: yes, the navigationcontroller disappears. I've put it in the appdeligate but it still doesnt work. here is a link to the source code. when you navigate away fromt he first tab, you can see that the navbar disappears. Could someone have a look, thanks. [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9778730/splittest.zip)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your navigationController is getting deallocated.
Put this statement before the "push" to find out:

```
   NSLog(@" Navigation Controller is 0x%x",myNavigationController);
```

If it reports  "0x0", then you need to keep a reference to your navController somewhere so it stays around.